# SecurityConfig results in TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after migrating from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to migrate an existing project from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.0 (3.0.11). As part of this change, I know I need to update the SecurityConfig I use for Spring Security.
In 2.7, I was able to successfully migrate from overriding `configure` (and extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) to creating a `filterChain` Bean. I also started making use of the new Lambda DSL syntax.

The 2.7 code that works looks something like:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> {
                authorizeRequests
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers(
                        "/images/**", 
                        "/js/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/login**",
                        "/logout",
                        ...
                    ).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
            }).formLogin(formLogin -> {
                formLogin
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll();
            }).logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }
```

I modified the code for Spring Boot 3.0 as follows:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);

        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> {
                authorizeRequests
                    .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/admin/**")).hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/images/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/js/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/css/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/login**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/logout")).permitAll()
                    
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            }).formLogin(formLogin -> {
                formLogin
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll();
            }).logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }
```

This new code returns an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` when I try to open the `/login` page in Google Chrome. From my understanding, this happens if the rules listed in my code above are not being properly parsed.

The endpoint of my login page is defined as:

```
@Controller
public class AppController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
    ...
}
```

This points to my `login.jsp` page

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get this to work in Spring Boot 3.0 .
NOTE: I am aware of Spring Boot 3.1, but I don't want to upgrade until I can get everything working in 3.0 (according to the documentation, 3.1 should not have any breaking changes).

Comment: Can you try to do what I wrote on my answer ?

Comment: So, SO marked this as a duplicate ... and the linked answer helped resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove next two lines of code from `filterChain`:

```
.requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/login**")).permitAll()
.requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/logout")).permitAll()
```

Because you have to declare it in `formLogin()` parameter.

Also be sure that you custom controller(login method) that is responsable to treat login look something like this

```
@Controller
class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

More details about it you can find if you will read [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html)

And also add one more `requestMatchers`

```
.requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/WEB-INF/**")).permitAll()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the two lines did not fix the issue. I have already defined my login controller as you have described

Comment: `.requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/WEB-INF/**")).permitAll()` this should help you.